# how to auto generate id in java textfield from mysql

Tags: java, mysql

**What I've tried:**

```
try
    {
        PreparedStatement pstat = con.prepareStatement("insert into student_info values (?,?,?,?)", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        pstat.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txtId.getText()));
        pstat.setString(2, txtFName.getText());
        pstat.setString(3, txtLName.getText());
        pstat.setString(4, gender);
        int result = pstat.executeUpdate();

        if(result > 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Inserted Succesfully !!!");
            txtId.setText("");              
            txtFName.setText("");
            txtLName.setText("");           
            bg.clearSelection();
            ResultSet rs = pstat.getGeneratedKeys();
            int newId= -1;
            if(rs != null && rs.next())
            {
                newId = rs.getInt(1);
                txtId.setText(String.valueOf(newId));
            }
        }
    }
```

**What I want:**

The new id to be displayed in the textbox

**What doesn't happen:**

The new id doesnt get displayed in textfield..

Comment: include the table definition for student_info please

Comment: id PK,
firstname varchar,
lastname varchar,
gender varchar

Comment: you are passing a value for the id already, so it is not generated

Comment: does that mean i need to remove PK or Id field from table

Comment: @ Jikesh Prajapati No need to passing a value to id through the query! and set id as aotoincrement in table.

Comment: @JikeshPrajapati That will depend if the `id` field is also auto incrementing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make this changes to your code:

```
PreparedStatement pstat = con
    .prepareStatement("insert into student_info (firstname,lastname,gender) 
        values (?,?,?)", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS); // omit id column
pstat.setString(1, txtFName.getText());
pstat.setString(2, txtLName.getText());
pstat.setString(3, gender);
int result = pstat.executeUpdate();
// now got fetch the generated id
```

Comment: it displays an error - column count doensn't match value count at row 1

Comment: have you made your ID column as AUTOGENERATED in the create query

Comment: are you sure you pasted the code like above? there are three `?` not four

Comment: yes. i did same as above. but it shows an exception   ... column count doensn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @JikeshPrajapati are you sure, sure, completly 100% sure? like you added the column names like `(firstname,lastname,gender) ` without the id?